# Protractor times out opening Chrome Driver on Centos

Tags: node.js, angularjs, google-chrome, npm, protractor

I am trying to run the angular-phonecat tutoral on Centos 6.5, Chrome version 33.0.1750.146, npm 1.4.3, and node version v0.10.31.  I am trying to run the protractor tests:

```
npm run protractor
```

But I get this error, how do I fix it?

```
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 preprotractor /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat
> npm run update-webdriver


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 preupdate-webdriver /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat
> npm install

npm WARN package.json karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4 No README data

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat
> bower install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 update-webdriver /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat
> webdriver-manager update

selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat
> protractor test/protractor-conf.js

Using ChromeDriver directly...

/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:87
      Error('Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at ' + url));
      ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1:50977/
at Error (<anonymous>)
at onResponse (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:87:11)
at /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:42:21
at /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/http/http.js:96:5
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:136:7)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:440:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:49)
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:111:30)
at Object.createDriver (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:460:30)
at ChromeDriverProvider.getDriver (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/chrome.js:67:27)
at /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:221:35
at _fulfilled (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
at /home/david/IdeaProjects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
```

Comment: Are you sure there is smth running at `http://127.0.0.1:50977`?

Comment: I thought it was spun up by the command?  The app site is on port 8000

Comment: you may need to run `webdriver-manager start` first to start selenium server (and if you didn't, run `webdriver-manager update`). read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into issues as well right, mostly because of the fact that ChromeDriver is not supported for Centos (ver 6.5 for me).

[This might help, but it didn't work for me](http://sifranklin.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/how-to-install-chromedriver-on-centos-6-5-using-vagrant/#more-87)